# Selecting Spicific data placed in the middle of the database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

how to determine which row number in my database will the **selection query** *start* to select and *the Limit* of the selection ,as I want to select piece of data which is located in the middle of my database table
I may use `between @indexOfSelection , @limitOfSelection` or something like that ,but I don't know how !

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ordered_articles
@LowerBound int,
@UpperBound int
    AS
    select * from orderedData where articleid between LowerBound and UpperBound ;

    with orderedData 
    (
    select * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() over ORDER BY (articleid)
    from articles
    )
    WHERE rn >= @LowerBound AND rn <= @UpperBound 
        RETURN
```

Comment: or my logic is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can make use of ROW_NUMBER Function something like this ....

```
;WITH OrderedData
 AS
 (
  SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn)
  FROM Table_Name
 )
SELECT * FROM OrderedData
WHERE rn >= @LowerLimit AND rn <= @UpperLimit
```

**Your Query**

```
select * from articles 
where articleid between @indexOfSelection AND @LimitOfselection
```

You just need to add the key word `AND` between your upper lower limit variable and upper limit variable.

**Your Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ordered_articles 
@LowerBound int, 
@UpperBound int 
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
   select * from articles 
   where articleid between @LowerBound and @UpperBound 
END
```

**To Select A range Of Rows**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ordered_articles 
@LowerBound int, 
@UpperBound int 
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
WITH OrderedData
AS
 (
  SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY articleid)
  FROM articles
 )
SELECT * FROM OrderedData
WHERE rn >= @LowerBound AND rn <= @UpperBound

END

 EXECUTE ordered_articles 10, 15  --<-- this will return 10 to 15 number row ordered by ArticleID
```

Comment: @AyaMohammad deleted some records ouch :) then you need to restore you database from you last full backup if you have backed up your database.

Comment: hmm , well it only checks if the *ARTICLEID* placed in some range of rows , but what I need is to check if the **ARTICLEID's row** is placed is some range

Comment: @AyaMohammad how do you define a Range ??

Comment: when you select ARTICLEIDs Between an upper limit and lower limit is this not a range ??

Comment: how come it's not a range ! , anyway I mean between the Upper and Lower Limits

Comment: @AyaMohammad I am sorry I am not sure what you are asking, if possible show some sample data in your question and the desired output maybe then I can help you.

Comment: this is what I did so far : ** CREATE PROCEDURE ordered_articles
 LowerBound int,
 UpperBound int,
 
AS
select * from orderedData where articleid between LowerBound and UpperBound ;

with orderedData 
(
select * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() over ORDER BY (articleid)
from articles
)
WHERE rn >= LowerBound AND rn <= UpperBound 
 RETURN**

Comment: @AyaMohammad you are using both queries in your procedure have a look I have updated my answer.

Comment: and what about the ROW_NUMBER() ? should I use it or not ! @M.Ali

Comment: @AyaMohammad you can use either of them but you dont need to use both of them I guess you should avoid using Row_Number() function as it will be an overkill for such a simple query.

Comment: look sir ... what I mean by Upperbound and LoweBound is the limits of the rows which I will select .... and for ex in the first time I want it to select from row 0 to row 3 , next time I want it to select from row 4 until row 7 and so on @M.Ali

Comment: @AyaMohammad now you are talking business, Have a look I have updated the answer the very last Stored Procedure in my answer will do the job

Comment: It says : Incorrect Syntax near 'select'
Incorrect Syntax near ')' O.o !! I dunno why !!!

Comment: @AyaMohammad  if the table name and column names are right just copy paste my code and execute it.

Comment: @AyaMohammad I was missing `AS` key word in my proc just copy paste the code and it should work sorry I didnt test it myself 1st